# What is the java.nio.file.Files equivalent of java.io.File.setWritable()?

Tags: java, cross-platform, file-permissions

The `java.io.File.setWritable()` method allows you to set a file to be writable for everybody on filesystems that support this in a platform independent way.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#setWritable(boolean,%20boolean)

What allows the equivalent behaviour on the `java.nio.file.Path` object?

The static method `java.nio.file.Files.setAttribute()` implies that it is possible to set permissions,

But there is no clear set of parameters that emulate the `java.io.File.setWritable()` method.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#setAttribute(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.nio.file.LinkOption...)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

NIO extends Java's IO but it is not a full replacement of existing classes. The  `java.io.File` class is also **not** deprecated. For `java.io.File.setWritable()` there's no equivalent within `java.nio.file.Files`. As already mentioned in a previous answer, you can still convert the Path object to a File object and call `setWritable`.

NIO introduces the notion of file attribute views and allows to access for example also Access Control Lists (ACLs) and user defined file attributes. E.g. on Windows `setWritable` has only an effect on the read-only flag (first tab within file explorer) but no effect on ACLs (see the security tab in the file explorer). Even when you call `file.setWritable(false)` the owner will still have permissions to write but finally cant write due to the set read-only flag.

Since not all operating systems are POSIX-compatible (greets to Redmond;-) not all file attributes views are available on all operating systems. The following code would more or less do the same as `java.io.File.setWritable`:

```
public static boolean setWriteable(Path path, boolean writeable) {

    try {
        PosixFileAttributeView posix = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, PosixFileAttributeView.class);

        if (posix != null) {

            // POSIX
            Set<PosixFilePermission> permissions = new HashSet<>(posix.readAttributes().permissions());
            boolean changed = false;
            if (writeable) {
                changed = permissions.add(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
            } else {
                changed = permissions.remove(PosixFilePermission.OWNER_WRITE);
            }

            if (changed) {
                posix.setPermissions(permissions);
            }
            return true;

        } else {

            // Windows - does not support POSIX file permission view
            DosFileAttributeView dos = Files.getFileAttributeView(path, DosFileAttributeView.class);
            if (dos != null) {
                dos.setReadOnly(!writeable);
            }
            return true;
        }
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

So, if you just want to change the read-only flag of a file I would stay with `File.setWritable`. Its simple and you do not have to care about the operating system / supported file attribute views. If you should need more (e.g. change the owner / group for a file or read/change ACLs) file attribute views should be your choice.

Comment: I was worried this was the case. The lack of a good string representation of the java permissions model makes setting cross-platform respecting permissions in config files tricky. Thank you for the comprehensive answer.

Answer (score 1):

Use 'setWritable' on the path's associated file object:

```
    import java.nio.file.Files;
    import java.nio.file.Path;
    import java.nio.file.Paths;

    public class Permissions {
      public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Path current = Paths.get(".");
        Path path = Files.createFile(current.resolve("permissions.txt"));
        path.toFile().setWritable(true, false);
      }
    }
```